CLI - using prompt:// doesn't yield same pubkey
When I generated my pubkey a few years ago I had to use prompt:// whenever using the command line because the normal pubkeys generated didn't match what I had.  I tried it today and its generating different pubkeys from prompt:// that don't match my pubkey.  What options do I need to use.  I tried ASK and it was also different output.

You might need to try a combination of things. If prompt:// and ASK aren't giving the expected output, you might need to try more options, mostly with the derivation path. Try some of the following:
solana-keygen pubkey prompt://?key=0/0
solana-keygen pubkey prompt://?key=0/1
solana-keygen pubkey prompt://?full-path=m/44/2017/0/1

Info taken from https://docs.solanalabs.com/cli/wallets/paper#public-key-derivation
